# Count total number of elements in array, that is greater than the previous element in the same array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am tracking numbers of miles run, for a sequence of long-distance runs. I want to count the number of times progress is made (i.e. the number of times a logged distance exceeded the previously logged distance).

I am convinced that the .every() method will be useful to me here. I need a counter, which increases by one every time it finds an item that was greater than the previous item. It is this last bit of functional logic that I cannot generate myself.

```
const progressDays = (runs) => {
return runs.reduce(aFunc, 0) 
   }

const aFunc = (total, num) => {
   //the logic I need goes here
}
}

console.log(progressDays([3, 4, 1, 2]))
```

I would expect the output of the above code to be 2, because on 2 occasions (3->4) and (1->2) progress was made.

Comment: "*I am convinced that the .every() method will be useful to me here*" how?

Comment: With so little posted here are you expecting someone to understand what you are saying and then provide a complete solution?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate starting at the second element, checking whether it's greater than `arr[i - 1]`:

```js
const progressDays = (runs) => {
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < runs.length; i++) {
    if (runs[i] > runs[i - 1]) {
      total++;
    }
  }
  return total;
}


console.log(progressDays([3, 4, 1, 2]))
```

`.reduce` doesn't work all that well here, because you don't want to iterate over *all* the days, only over every *gap* between array items, essentially.

Comment: Yeah, the only way I can see `reduce` working is to generate an array that contains pairs for sequential elements `[3, 4, 1, 2]` -> `[[3, 4], [4, 1], [1, 2]]` which you then call `reduce` on to sum only if `arr[1] > arr[2]`. Or run `filter` -> `reduce`. But that's overall ugly, a simple loop should be the correct answer here.

Comment: I was also thinking about using a test: `if (i === 0) return count /* rest of the code */` but yeah, gross

Answer (score 0):

You oculd reduce the array and take the actual value as well as the previous value from the array by a destructuring with the reduced index. Then count the with the condition.

```js
const
    progressDays = runs => runs.reduce(check, 0), 
    check = (total, num, i, { [i - 1]: prev }) => total + (prev < num);

console.log(progressDays([3, 4, 1, 2]));
```